# 2D animation on chrome OS

Tags: animation, 2d

How do you create a 2D animation using blender on Chrome OS? The tutorials I saw all didn't work, where you go to new file and select 2D animation.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little on what step of the tutorial "didn't work" for you? Did you not see the menu item, or was there some other issue?

Comment: I can click on new file, but it does not give me an option to create a 2d file. It just gives me another file that is exactly the same.

Comment: Try using the File menu in the top left corner. Go to File > New > 2D Animation